# Image with gestures - phonegap

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, cordova

I'm making an application who needs to display a map, contained in a large image file (png). The user must be able to zoom in/out the image and drag it in order to scroll the image with touch gestures.

I'm not sure that you get it, but i want to display a single image as it would be displayed by the "Photos" iphone application.

I would like some hints about the best way to do it with those gesture and with a navigation header in order to leave the image view.

Thanks in advance if you can give me any help about this issue because I did not find any clue on the phonegap doc.

/ouss

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the built inn components for this?

Sounds like you need to wrap an ImageView inside a ScrollView and a HorizontalScrollView, then rescale the image by handling onTouch-events.

Comment: I guess I have no choice than to go native and make a plugin... Pretty uncool since I will have to do a plugins for Android AND iPhone since I'm targetting on this devices. I guess I'll have to consider using Titanium then. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MapKitPlug plugin:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/MapKitPlug

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I knew about this plugin but i don't think it's what i want since a just a wrapper for the MKMapView ([see doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)) and can't display an image as a Map. So it's not what i'm looking. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would use http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 which has some really slick image zoom going on. You can also start loading new images after certain zoom levels for finer grains of quality.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Child Browser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser) phonegap plugIn. 
It is very simple and easy to implement.

It supports loading page from a url as well as you can show any kind of images.(**png, jpg, jpeg, bmp and gif**)